# Best way to send a QBitArray to QML App?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm quite a beginner in QtQuick, and I'm working on a small project where I have a C++ class (that I intend to register as a QML Type later) that, everytime my QML app feeds it some input, produce a QBitArray which gets read by QML and is outputted as a grid. (Basically, let's say I'm working on a 2D game with a board, where every cell has two possible states, and the list of states is produced by C++)

I'm wondering about the best way to make QML reads the BitArray. The most obvious solution to me would be to set it as a property, but QBitArray isn't a QObject (I guess I could inherit it and Qobject in a wrapper, but it feels unelegant).

I could also call a method of MyCLass wrapping the BitArray, but I'm wondering about threading overhead. If my object has been created in QML/JS, will there be overhead to call its C++ methods ?

So, in conclusion, what is the most elegant/efficient/idiomatic way to do this ?

Comment: QML mostly operates with JS types. How would you manage an array of bits in JS? The answer to this question will be the answer to yours. I would be convert it to `QList<bool>` since QML [supports it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array) transparently.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll look into it